# WooCommerce: Allow HTML tags in "add_fee function" label

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to add a custom fee based on payment method:

```
function stackoverflow_apply_payment_gateway_fee() {
 $payment_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' );
 if( $payment_method == 'paypal' ) {
 $label =  'PayPal Fee <span>HTML</span>';
 $cart_subtotal_fee = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
 $amount = 5;
 WC()->cart->add_fee( $label, $amount, true, 'standard' );
 }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'stackoverflow_apply_payment_gateway_fee' );
```

I want to show an icon next to the label using HTML, like this:

```
     $label =  'PayPal Fee <span>HTML</span>';
```

However string will be (esc_html) escaped for HTML tags. How can I make it work with HTML tags to show my icon?

Answer (score 3):

There is a filter hook called `esc_html` in WP esc_html function that you can use. you can append your icon HTML to your label. check below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function stackoverflow_apply_payment_gateway_fee() {
    $payment_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' );
    if( $payment_method == 'paypal' ) {
        $label             =  'PayPal Fee';
        $cart_subtotal_fee = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
        $amount            = 5;
        WC()->cart->add_fee( $label, $amount, true, 'standard' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'stackoverflow_apply_payment_gateway_fee' );

function show_an_icon_next_to_the_paypal_fee_label( $safe_text, $text ){
    if( ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) && $text == 'PayPal Fee' ){
        $safe_text = $safe_text.'<span>HTML</span>';
    }
    return $safe_text;
}
add_filter( 'esc_html', 'show_an_icon_next_to_the_paypal_fee_label', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: For a better performance, `is_cart() || is_checkout()` should wrap `add_filter` function.
So 
    if (is_cart() || is_checkout()) {
        add_filter( 'esc_html', 'show_an_icon_next_to_the_paypal_fee_label', 10, 2 );
    } 
and 
    if($text == 'PayPal Fee' ){
        $safe_text = $safe_text.'<span>HTML</span>';
    }

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to copy the templates over to your theme (or child theme) from the `woocommerce/templates` directory:

- checkout/review-order.php
- cart/cart-totals.php

In those files wou will find this code where the `esc_html` function is, and edit it as you need:

```php
    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
        <tr class="fee">
            <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); /* Leave this one */?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```